# separate get requests for each youtube video ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am trying to pass in each id from an array holding youtube IDs to a get request. The goal is to get names for each video ids and create a new array.

To start with this is what I am doing. I am getting an empty array

```
var x = ['CSvFpBOe8eY', 'Zi_XLOBDo_Y'];
var x_title = [];

for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    $.getJSON('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/' + x[i] + '?v=2&alt=jsonc', function (data, status, xhr) {
        x_title[i]= data.data.title;
    });    
}

console.log(x_title)
```

Here is the fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/sghoush1/Cnepk/5/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The array is blank because it's getting printed out before all the getJSON calls are complete. But, you have another issue as well.

`i` is not scoped for each loop so you'll end up using the last value of `i` by the time the requests are completed.

You'll need to wrapper the inner loop with and IIFE (Immediately Invoked Function Execution) and pass `i` into it, or, use the `forEach` api of the Array.

Example of using IIFE http://jsfiddle.net/jj7Pg/

```
for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    (function(_i){
        $.getJSON('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/' + x[_i] + '?v=2&alt=jsonc', function (data, status, xhr) {
            x_title[_i]= data.data.title;
            console.log(x_title);
        }); 
   }(i));
}
```

Example of `forEach` http://jsfiddle.net/jj7Pg/1/

```
x.forEach(function(item, indx){
    $.getJSON('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/' + item + '?v=2&alt=jsonc', function (data, status, xhr) {
        x_title[indx]= data.data.title;
        console.log(x_title);
    });
});
```

I would go with the `forEach` approach if you're working with newer browsers. Compatibility list can be found here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#Browser_compatibility

Answer (score 2):

This is actually working fine but you are getting an empty array because your `getJSON` call is asynchronous and your `console.log` is firing before it has returned data.

[Example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j5zr4/), note the work is done inside the success callback function.

Comment: One fine day I will stop making these rookie mistakes....thanks for pointing this out danjam